# Remove &amp; (&) sign from class value & lowercase classes names

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I've created form for repairing/selling iOS devices using WP Gravity Forms. I assigned classes to each `<li>` element based on its child's `<input>` tag. But now I'm facing some issues, some of these are fixed but one of these is still not fixed yet.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkb57/562/)

If you can see above fiddle example that i've created, you can see there that I'm getting value from each `<input>` tag, and assigning the same value to its parent tag. I've also fixed spacing issue, but i still can't fix the **'&'** issue which is **'at&t'** network.

And also i want to lowercase the value of each class that is assigned e.g like **16GB => 16gb**. I did try `.toLowerCase();` but it didn't work. So any help regarding this would be appreciable. thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to replace the **&**:

```
var newStr = inputClass.replace("&", "");
```

And to use lower case use:

```
$(this).closest('p').addClass('prefix-' + newStr.toLowerCase());
```

Your whole jQuery code should now be:

```
$('p').find('input').each(function () {
    var inputClass = $(this).attr('value');
    var newStr = inputClass.replace("&", "");
    $(this).closest('p').addClass('prefix-' + newStr.toLowerCase());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkb57/563/)

Comment: I was gonna post, but this is so close to mine that I won't bother.  You should use `.val()` to get the input value as well though :)

Comment: Thanks you guys it works for me. Thanks again i appreciate it. And this issue could help others :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove `&` from `at&t` try this

```
var newStr = inputClass.replace(/&|\s+/g, '');
```

and for lower case

```
$(this).closest('p').addClass('prefix-' + newStr.toLowerCase());
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/Rkb57/566/